# <select> showing more than one field using ng-options query

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Currently, I have an angular.js `<select>` filled by the following query:

```
c.ip for c in cameras track by c.idCamera
```

and it produces on my `<select>` something like:

```
<option value="1">192.168.0.121</option>
<option value="2">192.168.0.122</option>
<option value="3">192.168.0.123</option>
...
```

my `$scope` has a list of cameras and I can see the IP, but I want to use two fields as label -- let's say camera's **IP** and **type**.

I'm looking way to produce as output something like this:

```
<option value="1">192.168.0.121 - ZOOM</option>
<option value="2">192.168.0.122 - PAN </option>
<option value="3">192.168.0.123 - ZOOM</option>
...
```

I'm currently using angular.js beta 6, if that has any additional bearing on the matter.

Answer (score 4):

The `label` in the [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive is an expression like all the others. It can be as complex as you want:

```
<select ng-model="myCamera" ng-options="(c.ip + ' - ' + c.type) for c in cameras track by c.idCamera"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
(c.ip + ' ' + c.yourField) for c in cameras track by c.idCamera
```